# Find the order of the views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a `RelativeLayout` that includes a set of buttons. During app execution the order of buttons is changed.

How to find the order of the buttons in `onDestroy()`?

Comment: What language do you use ?

Comment: I use java but platform is Android and IDE is eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < parentLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    View child = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);
    // other logic here
}
```

Comment: very good. Thank you so much. for me the following code is perfect:  
  for(int i=0; i<layout.getChildCount(); i++)
  {
   Button Bt=(Button) layout.getChildAt(i) ;
   CharSequence St= Bt.getText();
   Log.i("order",(String) St);
   
  }